# 3 Different Shaped Divs together

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help me. I have this idea to create 3 divs with different shapes. 1st triangle 2nd rhombus 3rd triangle. When putting together they make one rectangle. I created 3 div figures but have a problem putting them together. I will appreciate your help.

Note: I have tried flex but then the main div is separated into 3 parallel sections.

HTML

```css
.triangle {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: grey;
}

.triangle .figure_1 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background: green;
}

.triangle .figure_2 {
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
  background: yellow;
}

.triangle .figure_3 {
  width: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle" class="triangle">
  <div id="figure_1" class="figure_1">

  </div>
  <div id="figure_2" class="figure_2">

  </div>
  <div id="figure_3" class="figure_3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a mistake with CSS selector, when you have an `id`, you select it using `#` not `.`. For Example: `#triangle .figure_3`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your triangle as relative and figure as absolute

```css
.triangle {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle .figure_1 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.triangle .figure_2 {
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0%);
  background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.triangle .figure_3 {
  width: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  background: red;
      position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle" class="triangle">
  <div id="figure_1" class="figure_1">

  </div>
  <div id="figure_2" class="figure_2">

  </div>
  <div id="figure_3" class="figure_3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcom!